# juju install error : couldn't connect to host

Tags: software-installation, juju, proxy

I'm trying to install juju on MAAS ubuntu 12.04.04 .

```
I get the following error :-
root@ubuntu:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 128, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
root@ubuntu:~#
```

I have tried setting proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` as well as setting `http_proxy`environment variable.

I'm able to download any packages from internet though e.g. vim etc.

Please let me know what I may be missing here.

Comment: For one, you don't need `sudo` if you're already root. Not sure if that causes your problem, but it might mess with the environment variables. Either use `sudo` as normal user or don't as a superuser.

Comment: @kraxor I tried without sudo (when logged in as root) - no luck. Do I need to add a node in MAAS for this to work? I haven't done that because I couldn't figure out how to do that so far.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "installing juju on MAAS"? It seems you're trying to install the juju client on a machine, provisioned by MAAS. If you want to use juju to deploy services on MAAS, you'll need to install juju on your machine and configure your `$HOME/.juju/environments.yaml` with credentials for your MAAS (see the MAAS documentation for details - http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html). Then, you can use `juju bootstrap` from your machine to create an environment and later `juju deploy` to deploy some services.